# API Instagram: как пропарсить страницу

Tags: json, javascript, instagram

Приходит JSON такого вида

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "data": [{
        "attribution": null,
        "tags": ["02q"],
        "location": null,
        "comments": {
            "count": 71,
            "data": [{
                "created_time": "1349883158",
                "text": "Great shot\u2661",
                "from": {
                    "username": "sakura_yumi",
                    "profile_picture": "http:\/\/images.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_54578142_75sq_1348218646.jpg",
                    "id": "54578142",
                    "full_name": "yumi"
                },
                "id": "299164076294750525"
            },
```

Я думаю, что наверняка есть готовый пример, как пропарсить такой ответ. Прошу помочь кодом.

Comment: @AlexRudenkiy, что-то мне сомнительными тут эти метки кажутся. Особенно про api.

Answer (score 2):

Если данный JSON текст у вас в переменной напр. `JSONtext`, то так:

```
var Insta = eval( '(' + JSONtext + ')' );
var code = Insta.meta.code; /* 200 */
alert( Insta.data.comments.count + ' комментов');
```

JSON имеет изначально «родной» для JavaScript синтакс. Можно и так прямо писать:

```
var iObject = { "meta": { "code": 200 }};
alert( iObject.meta.code );
```

Comment: нет, данный JSON текст не в переменной у меня, я его фактически просто забираю из API, то есть это страница

Comment: Чем забираете?

Comment: да, в принципе ничем. ещё не думал насчёт этого. думал пока рукой просто копировать всё и проверять парсер. или это не правильный подход?

Comment: Непонятно, что вы делаете, зачем, и какие планы )

Comment: просто интересно поработать с АПИ Инстаграма, хочу парсить оттуда фотографии с определённым хэштегом

Comment: к примеру, у меня есть определенная страница

я надеюсь правильно, понимаю, сначала гетом указываю нужную мне страницу, затем провожу парсинг?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="images">

</div>
<script>
$.getJSON("http://api.instagram.com/",

//КАК МНЕ ЗДЕСЬ СДЕЛАТЬ ТО ЧТО НУЖНО)))
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1):

на jquery распарсить такой ответ в объект можно вызовом метода [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: спасибо, попробую разобраться